# How to increase polycount without messing up my quad topology?

Tags: modeling, topology

I have a clean quad topology,
however. I want to increase the polycount on this part.
[image: that's the part where I want to increase a poly count]

But if I use to cut, there is a spare vertex point at the top.

[image: spare vertex point]

I'm planning on using this model in a blender animation. Therefore I want to avoid triangles as much as possible. So is it okay if I keep a spare vertex point there making it a pentagon? What's gonna happen if do?

Comment: This is very informative : https://topologyguides.com/loop-reduction

Comment: Good question.  I would carefully select the "extra" vertex and verify that there's only one vertex and not several at the same location.  Move it in a perpendicular direction, be sure that there are 3 surfaces using the vertex -- that no "hole" appears.  Render from multiple angles to decide if it distorts acceptably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically going to have to choose one of three options,

Either try to solve the geo like this, diverting it into two triangles:
[image]

[image]

Or just let the subdivision sort itself out. It all gets turned into quads when you apply one level of subdivision anyways.

Personally I think the latter looks better.

[image]

[image]

None of it really looks very good IMO though.

[image]

Consider whether you even need to do this, if you really need that geo there then maybe you can apply an additional level of subdivision over the entire mesh and then work from there with your new geo. Trying to insert too much manual geometry into a  mesh starts to get distorted and shitty quickly. All of the options from above result in something far worse than this option.